# Get-AzureService does not list all cloud services (multiple subscriptions)

Tags: powershell, deployment, azure, cloud

I got two azure subscriptions (sub1 and sub2). Requesting the cloud services in powershell with `Get-AzureService` does only list the services from sub1 and not sub2.

I also tryed to set the azure subscription using `Set-AzureSubscription` for sub2, without success.

How can I get the services in powershell from sub2?

Comment: define `without success`. Also, have you included the management certificate for sub2 also? It is not just setting sub2. You have to upload the management certificate explicitly for all the subscriptions you want to manage. This is done in the portal -> Settings -> Management Certificates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ohhh, I got it:

`Set-AzureSubscription -DefaultSubscription "sub2"`

Answer (score 2):

This has actually changed in recent PowerShell versions. -DefaultSubscription no longer exists as a parameter.

You should now use Select-AzureSubscription http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495203.aspx

> Select-AzureSubscription -Current "sub2"
>
> Get-AzureSubscription | fl SubscriptionName, SubscriptionId, IsDefault, IsCurrent

Answer (score 1):

The others methods doesn't works for me, so here's my two cents:

Get the list of subscriptions:

```
Get-AzureRmSubscription
```

Select the subscription using the subscription Id provided by the other call

```
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" -Current
```